# Is "banana" the shortest overlap word?

Tags: vocabulary, is-it-a-word

Banana, alfalfa, entente: these are words containing an overlap, that is, the pattern XYXYX where X and Y are replaced by letters or sequences of letters. The idea is that the two occurrences of XYX overlap.

Is there any 5-letter English word like that?
Any other examples besides the ones I mentioned?

Comment: It rather depends what you accept as a "word". You could have UrbanDictionary's [***bobob***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bobob) (acronym for *Big Ole Bitch On a Bike*), for example. But I think the question is Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Off Topic", how so?

Comment: Because it's not about English ***Usage***. You're just asking for a list of words matching some arbitrary orthographic criteria (it's irrelevant that imho it would be an *empty* list unless you include "words" not normally found in dictionaries).

Comment: I think overlaps may be problematic as it sounds like one is repeating oneself. So it is interesting to learn to what extent such things are tolerated in languages.

Comment: I think I can safely assure you there's no inherent tendency for languages to "tolerate" such replications in the sense you imply. English definitely *encourages* certain "reduplication" forms. But your examples are just "quirks" - they say nothing about how English "works".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you were to close, surely it should be because this is a "duplicate question" ;).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the FreeBSD operating system /usr/share/dict/words list, the following words of 6 letters or fewer match the pattern:

```
ajaja
alala
anana
arara
ululu
Bororo
Carara
Macaca
amamau
ananas
ararao
auhuhu
banana
batata
marara
rococo
venene
```

I believe the word list is based on (but not identical to) the 1934 Webster's New International Dictionary, Second Edition.

I generated the list with:

```
egrep '(.)(.)\1\2\1' /usr/share/dict/words | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
```

Comment: I guess "banana" is the only one on that list that's really well known.

Comment: I'd definitely say it's the best-known, but _[rococo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rococo)_ might meet the threshold of well-known, and _Macaca_ had [an unfortunate moment in the spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaca_(term)) recently.

Comment: OED has ***alala** - battle cry of the ancient Greeks, **anana** - uncommon variant of 'ananas',* and ***ululu** - wail of lamentation*. So +1 for having three terms that by at least one definition (they're in OED) meet OP's criteria.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Running (a derivative of) that pattern on the OED yields these additional six-letter solutions: *berere, derere, desese, hadada, halala, Ibibio, **mañana**, marara, matata,
ototoi, patata, pewewe, sememe, shshsh, tarara, wenene, zanana*.  As you see by *mañana*, I ignored diacritics (and case). The change compared with the original to make it insensitive to diacritics or case was this `(?xi) (?=(\w)) \X (?=(\w)) \X \1 \pM* \2 \pM* \1 \pM*` run on NFD data. BTW, seven-letter OED solutions are *awaward, bararag, heleles, ngarara, ogogoro, ototomy, phememe, phenene, ukelele*.

Comment: @tchrist: I can't believe that thus far only one other person has voted alongside me to close this totally meaningless question. None of the three qualifying ***five-letter*** words (which OP specifically asked for) are in my Official Scrabble Words. Which I happen to have an electronic copy of, so I could also knock out a few lines of code to search for others (which I still doubt exist). But this site is about *language*, not programming, so I won't bother.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You appear to be lost. This is my answer to the question. Meta is down the hall, second door on the left.

Comment: @ coneslayer: I suppose if the question hasn't been closed when I come back tomorrow I probably *will* complain on meta. I can understand the possibility of certain "pattern matching" issues being On Topic for ELU, but surely not this one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And if it were emigrated to SO, it would be closed for asking whether something was an English word. If it were sent to Linguistics, then it would be closed for asking about English-specific matters instead of more language-neutral ones, or perhaps about things deemed beneath the dignity and interest of that august community. I’m sure we can think of other SE sites where the question’s germanity could also reasonably apply — yet where it would be met with scorn equal to your own. [Nobody has a home for these sorts of questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145462).

Comment: @tchrist: It's up to the ELU community at large whether a question like this should be accepted - and if history is anything to go by, the majority will downvote me on meta if I post a question saying I think it *shouldn't*. But at least people should have to justify *why* they want to keep it open, and I certainly don't think *"Since no other SO site would take it, ELU should step up to the plate"* is a valid reason.